# Сравнение текущего значения с предыдущим

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, коллекции

```
can_1 = close_price[1:] # список начиная со второго значения
prev_val = close_price  # список целиком с первым значением

for x in can_1:
    for y in prev_val:
        if x > y:
            print('up')
        elif x < y:
            print('down')
```

Подскажите как сравнить *2-ое* значение с *1-м*, *3-ие* значение со *2-м*, *4-ое* с *3-м* и т.д.
Выдает некорректный ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для сравнения не нужно было создавать второй список, достаточно правильно работать с индексами:

```
items = [2, 8, 9, 1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5]

for i in range(1, len(items)):
    a, b = items[i - 1], items[i]

    if a < b:
        print('{} < {}'.format(a, b))
    elif a > b:
        print('{} > {}'.format(a, b))
    else:
        print('{} = {}'.format(a, b))
```

Результат:

```
2 < 8
8 < 9
9 > 1
1 < 3
3 < 6
6 < 7
7 > 4
4 < 5
5 = 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Жадный вариант, чтобы попарно обойти список. Простой код для [небольших] списков:

```
for a, b in zip(items, items[1:]):
    if a < b:
        print('up')
    elif a > b:
        print('down')
```

Для произвольных коллекций, [можно `pairwise()` рецепт из `itertools` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

for a, b in pairwise(items):
    if a < b:
        print('up')
    elif a > b:
        print('down')
```